# form won't submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with my form submission and here is the deal. I'm creating an image website and I want to create comments for every image so I have a anchor link which when clicked on shows the comments form, that is loads the html into the web page which wasn't inside at first place, so the form loaded inside the page is not submitting.

Is it possible that forms which are dnynamicly loaded into webpage can't submit? what can be other problems with this? I even tried putting something like `<a href="#" id="test">Click me</a>` inside the loaded content and I added

```
$("#test").click(function(){
alert("SOMETHING");
});
```

to my javascript and it won't alert as well.. what am I doing wrong ?

**EDIT**

Ok here is how I load form ..

I have an anchor link below my image :

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="showComments('22');" class="answer_comment">Add image content</a>
```

Here is javascript which is outside document ready function :

```
function showComments(post){
         var xHTML = "<div class=\"addComment\">";
         xHTML += "<form action=\"<?=base_url()?>images/post_comment/" + post + "\" method=\"post\" id=\"comment_form\" name=\"comment_form\">";
         xHTML += "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"comment_post_id\" name=\"comment_post_id\" value=\"" +post + "\"/>"; 
         xHTML += "<textarea name=\"comment_text\" class=\"comment\" rows=\"8\" cols=\"40\"></textarea>";
     .....
```

Like this I fill up my comments form.. need more code ?

Comment: What does the HTML look like that you are fetching?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dynamically loaded elements have to be rigged up as well in your case to alert, you want:

```
$("#test").live('click', function() {
  alert("SOMETHING");
});
```

This will fire for any element with `id="test"`, whether it's ajax loaded or not.  The same style should be used for whatever handler you want to use.  Read the [`.live()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/) for the full story...basically it sits up at the root DOM level listening for clicks and acts on them, so it doesn't care what was or wasn't there when you defined the event handler, which is what you want for dynamically loaded content.

Comment: you are right, the click function isn't working but yours with live it is working, why is that ?

Comment: Because when you set the `click` event, it applies only to the DOM elements *already there* at the moment of settings, but not future ones. +1 - I never understood what `live` was good for, now I do.

Comment: @Nick Craver me neither got the live thing until now, great answer, totally nailed it + 1 + accept

Comment: I wonder if jQuery should have been designed to make 'live' functionality the default behavior when assigning a handler (with an option to disable), since it seems to be a sticking point for many people.

Comment: @patrick - A global setup for this might make sense, for the non-ajax page loading handlers on a single element though, it is more expensive having all the hanlders up top.  I agree that a single setter like `$.defaultLive=true;` would be **very** nice in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need a `{` after the function ()  ?

and a `}' before the`);` in the third line ?

```
$("#test").click(function() {
alert("SOMETHING"); 
});
```

Comment: Ok sorry ... when I don't know the answer to a question immediatly, I tend to look at the syntax of the code posted. It happened to me a few times to be searching for errors just to find out (after a long time) that the syntax of the code is wrong. Especially with javascript this can be hard to find immediatly. But maybe I'm the only one making such mistakes. Great aqccepted answer to your question though - I have learned something today.

Answer (score 0):

Fetching a form using AJAX is usually not a problem.

The only reasons that come to mind why a form wouldn't submit:

- It's not valid HTML - should be possible to find out using firebug
- When submitting, you are addressing it through its ID (like `$('#comment_form').submit();`) which fails because there is already some element with that ID. To find out whether this is the case, try injecting a normal `<input type=submit>` inside the form and see whether that works.
- You are injecting it into another `<form>` element - easy to find out with Firebug

Answer (score 0):

You are adding an extra `{` to your code at the end:

```
$("#test").click(function()
alert("SOMETHING");
{);
```

Correct that and if it still doesn't work, try this which uses `live` method which works for *present as well as future* elements.

```
$("#test").live('click', function(){
  alert("something");
});
```

Also, make sure that if there are more than one forms, they are not over-lapping.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically added forms should behave the same as the ones to be found in the original html. Make sure that you add the event handler after the element is added or that you use the [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method.